# How to parse data from MUI Table to POST API

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, insert

I want to insert data into the API. for that I created a function called sendGameDetails. but how to get each insert value? I'm not connected to API yet. just I want to parse input values to the state. I'm using one usestate to getting data from API. should I need to create another state? how to i solve this. I'm beginner for react js.Please help me

```
import React from 'react';`enter code here`
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { getCategoryAction } from 'store/actions/gameView/gameData.action.js';

// ==============================|| CATEGORY TABLE ||============================== //

import MaterialTable from 'material-table';

function CatagoryTable() {
    //create state for categories
    const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);

    //create state for store new data
    // const [newData, setData] = useState('');

    const columns = [
        { title: 'Category Name', field: 'categoryName', filterPlaceholder: 'Search Category Name' },
        { title: 'Category Description', field: 'description', filtering: false, style: { width: 900 } }
    ];

    //create post method to post categories
    const sendGamedetails = () => {
        if (tableData) {
            console.log('sendGamedetails ');
        }
    };

    //use effect for get categories
    useEffect(() => {
        getCategoryAction().then((data) => {
            console.log('data ', data);
            setTableData(data);
        });
    }, []);
    return (
        <div>
            <MaterialTable
                style={{ width: 1200 }}
                columns={columns}
                data={tableData}
                //create table add row function
                editable={{
                    onRowAdd: (newRow) =>
                        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                            // console.log('newRow ', newRow);
                            setTableData([...tableData, newRow]);
                            sendGamedetails();
                            setTimeout(() => resolve(), 500);
                        }),
                    //create table update row function
                    onRowUpdate: (newRow, oldRow) =>
                        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                            const updatedData = [...tableData];
                            updatedData[oldRow.tableData.id] = newRow;
                            setTableData(updatedData);
                            console.log(newRow, oldRow);
                            setTimeout(() => resolve(), 500);
                        }),
                    //create table delete row function
                    onRowDelete: (selectedRow) =>
                        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                            const updatedData = [...tableData];
                            updatedData.splice(selectedRow.tableData.id, 1);
                            setTableData(updatedData);

                            // console.log('selectedRow ', selectedRow);
                            setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1000);
                        })
                }}
                //add custom button for save data in database
                // actions={[
                //     {
                //         icon: () => <button>click</button>,
                //         tooltip: 'Save Data',
                //         onClick: (e, data) => {
                //             console.log('rowData ', data);
                //         }
                //     }
                // ]}
                title="Add Game Categories"
                options={{ search: true, searchFieldVariant: 'outlined', filtering: true, addRowPosition: 'first', actionsColumnIndex: -1 }}
            />
        </div>
    );
}

export default CatagoryTable;
```